# Можно определить часовой пояс через php?

Tags: php, дата, время

Можно определить часовой пояс через php?

Дату в часовом поясе по умолчанию можно получить так:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date("M d Y H:i:s");
?>
```

А как узнать часовой пояс подключившегося клиента?

Возможно это сделать только с помощью *php*, или нужен ещё и *javascript*?

Comment: посмотрите, например, ответы к [этому](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1905397/4827341) и к [этому](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16525617/4827341) вопросам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На *сервере* вы можете узнать узнать часовой пояс *сервера*, что в большинстве случаев абсолютно бесполезно, потому что логика скрипта будет зависеть от того, какие настройки на сервере. В связи с этим эта функциональность удалена из `date_default_timezone_get`, начиная с PHP 5.4.

Чтобы узнать время на *клиенте*, то придётся спросить *клиент*. Для этого вам понадобится JavaScript и функция `getTimezoneOffset()`. Но даже в этом случае учтите, что не у всех пользователей корректно выставлен часовой пояс, а JavaScript сообщает только о смещении часового пояса, что недостаточно для определения часового пояса.

В целом, если ваш сервис ограничен географически, то часто достаточно установить часовой пояс по умолчанию и не заморачиваться. Для российских сервисов дата по Москве — это нормально и ожидаемо. Если вы хотите сделать сервис удобным для пользователей в любой точке планеты, то предоставьте пользователю возможность выбора часового пояса и пытайтесь угадать часовой пояс по информации, предоставляемой JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить IP адрес пользователя и по нему узнать часовой пояс

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PeterOlson отчего же? Не лучший способ определения часового пояса клиента, но всё же способ. Можно посмотреть [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743505/), например.

Comment: @Regent Хм, может быть я не достаточно внимательно в очереде проверок сделал. Но все же: я бы комментировал с таким рекомендацией, а не отправил ответ, потому что нет деталей о том, как узнать часовой пояс от адреса IP. Но так как репутация Andrey'а еще меньше 15, я не уверен, стоит ли отправить такой ответ.