# Вывести клиенту правильное время

Tags: php, javascript, время

В БД заношу время в формате time(), т.е. в секундах. Когда клиенту возвращается время операции, то он видит серверное время, а не свое. Как правильно конвертировать серверное время?

Как идея - это узнать время в секундах на устройстве, с запросом отправить это время на сервер. Там вычислить разницу.

Подскажите, если у кого есть готовый алгоритм и код.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435689/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php

Comment: `new Date(timestampFromPhp*1000)`

Comment: timestampFromPhp - что это?

Comment: это результат вызова функции `time()` на сервере (в `php`)

Answer (score 0):

Функция `time()`, которую вы используете, возвращает UNIX-timestamp, который в свою очередь примечателен тем, что не зависит от часового пояса(секунды отсчитываются по Гринвичу).

Передав его на клиент, вы можете инстанциировать объект даты с его помощью, причём дата будет интерпретировать UNIX-timestamp корректно, с учётом текущего часового пояса клиента.

Единственный момент, который нужно учесть - в js timestamp задаётся в миллисекундах:

```js
//let ts = <?=time()?>;
let ts = 1488575448;
let now = new Date(ts * 1000);

console.log(now.toTimeString());

// Разумеется, время можно форматировать самостоятельно
console.log(
[
  now.getHours(),
  now.getMinutes(), 
  now.getSeconds()]
  .map(d => d < 10 ? '0'+d : d)
  .join(':'));
```